# How to get tests to run with unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Wanted to use unittest for some data examples.

```
import unittest

from peculiar.py import misma_paridad, alterna_paridad


class TestMismaParidad(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_misma_paridad(self):
        self.assertTrue(misma_paridad(0, 0))
        self.assertFalse(misma_paridad(0, 1))

class TestAlternaParidad(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_alterna_paridad(self):
        self.assertTrue(alterna_paridad(1234))
        self.assertFalse(alterna_paridad(1224))


unittest.main()
```

After several attempts of editing code, still getting:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Can someone tell me where the issue might be?

Comment: I think you need to run your code from the command line using something like `python3 -m unittest my_code.py`

Comment: got this when doing so:

ERROR: peculiar-testing (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'peculiar-testing'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)

Comment: The `from peculiar.py import misma_paridad, alterna_paridad` is wrong. It should be `from peculiar import misma_paridad, alterna_paridad`. The results posted in your question just means all the unit tests ran and the assertions were all `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a blank `__init__.py` file to the same folder my test was in fixed it for me